# What can I do to retrieve windows that have gone off screen?

Tags: windows-xp, window

I am having a weird issue with a machine where sometimes when a window is initialized, it will shoot off screen and out of sight. I am unable to click on it to drag it back to sight.

Are there any programs or fixes for this in Windows XP?

I know Windows and other programs like to save window locations after they close so when you reopen them they are in the spot where they were closed and I cannot see any of these windows that were closed off screen.

Comment: It might be useful to note that both the ALT+SPACE, M and right-click on taskbar tricks in the answers work on most UNIX-like systems' window managers as well, making this a relatively universal trick.  Additionally, if you even have a tiny subset of the window on UNIX systems, you can usually ALT+CLICK on it to drag it.  I know this is a Windows-specific question, which is why I'm not leaving this as a full-fledged answer, but it might help someone coming from Google.

Comment: Did You connect second monitor recently? Or maybe a projector? This happens when You add second monitor device and strech your desktop (sometimes)

Comment: Asked 6 months ago, so, "see also": http://superuser.com/questions/239891/how-to-move-unseen-windows-cannot-access-my-application-after-switching-monito/

Comment: See also [How to move windows that open up offscreen?](http://superuser.com/q/53585/150988) and [Keyboard shortcut for moving a window to another screen](http://superuser.com/q/62603/150988).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Highlight in in the task bar, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd>. That will get it ready to move. Then use your arrow keys to move it and hit Enter when finished.

Try holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while closing. That often saves the location.

Comment: Also, right-click on the program item in the task bar, select Move, then, without moving your mouse again, press the right, left, up, or down arrow keys as appropriate until the window comes into view.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Will mark as the answer once the timeout expires.

Comment: @qroberts I am not sure why it is not universal, but the Shift trick works for some programs nicely, saving the position when it may not otherwise save. Thank you for marking it. I appreciate it.

Comment: I am curious as to why certain machines like to do this, it isn't just the one application either. I am thinking a driver or some input device may be messing with it, but the mouse isn't causing the move event. I am interested into what the cause may be if you know what it is (I am still going to mark you as the answer).

Comment: @qroberts Without seeing it, it is hard to know exactly, but I just did another search, and I found this interesting thread. You might want to go through it (It is for Windows 7, but probably still relevant. It is 22 pages, which is why I did not go through the whole thing). I suspect that there might be a default window position somewhere in the registry, but I could not find it. Writing that just gave me an idea: Try opening a window, and open Computer>Tools>Folder Options>View and make a change to a setting and click "Apply to all folders", or just try the "Reset folders". If there is a...

Comment: default, this might reset it.

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors? I've had several applications that couldn't quit understand how I had my dual monitors set up and would consistently open off screen if I closed them from my secondary monitor.

Comment: After pressing Alt+space, and then using one of the arrow buttons to move it a little, you can also then simply move the mouse and the window will jump under your mouse cursor.

Comment: @sidran32 Good point, but for some reason that doesn't work sometimes. I've used this trick for ages and the keyboard always works, but sometimes the mouse just does nothing

Comment: @qroberts @KCotreau: The shift trick only works if the program asks [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680%28VS.85%29.aspx) (or, in .Net, the [`FormStartLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx)) to use the default start position.  There are plenty of programs (and perhaps frameworks?) which don't use the default location, either with valid reason, or because the developer forgot/made a mistake/doesn't know any better *(it's not a bug you'd normally notice...)*

Comment: @BlueRaja The program was Simply Accounting if that helps you (I believe it uses .NET)

Comment: Works on Windows 8.  Thanks for saying alt and space THEN m.  That helped clarify this for me.

Comment: Lord God, thanks for this! I'm using a windows in German and I don't understand anything

Comment: what is this feature of one letter shortcut called? I am trying to find something similar for linux environment.

Answer (score 18):

I have a geeky solution :-) Script in Python that goes through all off-screen windows and offers moving them to the left upper corner:

```
import winxpgui, sys, win32con

screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1200

def WindowsListEnum(hwnd, data):
    pos = winxpgui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    left, top = 0, 0
    if pos[0] < 0 or pos[0] > screen_width:
        left = 10
    if pos[1] < 0 or pos[1] > screen_height:
        top = 10
    if left or top:
        print winxpgui.GetWindowText(hwnd), ',', pos, '->', (top, left, pos[2], pos[3])
        if sys.stdin.read(1) == 'y':
            winxpgui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, left, top, pos[2]-pos[0], pos[3]-pos[1], win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW)

print "press 'y' to move the window, anything else to continue\n"
winxpgui.EnumWindows(WindowsListEnum, None)
```

You need [Python](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/) and [Win32all](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build216/).

Comment: Yeah, you could download and install stuff (3-5 minutes), **OR** you could use shortcut keys (3-5 seconds)...

Comment: I usually use the shortcut too but sometimes it does not work or I need to move more Windows at once.

Comment: Completely overkill but I like it

Comment: +1. This is useful if the window is completely offscreen and in an unknown direction (or very far offscreen).

Comment: @Peter: in that case you could use alt-space followed by x, which maximizes the window

Answer (score 15):

In Windows 7 you can select the window and then <kbd>Win</kbd> + arrow keys to move it.

Comment: Note that the question asked about Windows XP, but this is a great trick for Windows 7 which I do use sometimes myself.

Answer (score 9):

You can also right-click on the taskbar and choose one of the window-arranging menu choices. In Windows 7, they are:

- Cascade Windows
- Show Windows Stacked
- Show Windows Side-by-side

Previous versions used slightly different terms, but did the same thing. Some versions will only arrange non-minimized windows/applications, if I recall correctly.

---

[image]

Comment: This method also affects all the other visible windows.

Comment: That's true @Synetech but when you are desperate to get back an offscreen window during a presentation, you don't mind getting messy...

Answer (score 6):

1. Set focus to the window, by clicking in the task bar or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to bring up the system menu.
3. <kbd>M</kbd> to select Move.
4. Tap an arrow key once to start moving the window.
5. Move your mouse.

The window will quickly pop in to view.

This is faster than using the arrows to move the window the whole way, especially if it is way off screen.

Comment: You don’t need both axes; *any* arrow key will do.

Comment: @Synetechinc: I just confirmed that in Windows 7; you are right. I learned this sequence long ago, so it may have been required in earlier versions of Windows / NT. If anyone has that info, I will update my answer.

Comment: Hmm, that seems strange, I can’t imagine why both would be required. I know any arrow key was sufficient at least back to Win95. Maybe you just pressed both and thought that’s what did it, like pressing a bunch keys in a game to do something and not knowing which one did the trick, so you just repeat them all each time. `:-)`

Answer (score 5):

One extra tip: after you have started moving it with the keyboard (one pixel), finish by just moving the mouse. That is a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

@qrobers [as noted by StevenV](https://superuser.com/questions/316282/what-can-i-do-to-retrieve-windows-that-have-gone-off-screen/316358#316358)

Right click on the taskbar window button and tell it to

- Cascade Windows (stacks windows on top of each other with the windows headers showing)
- Tile Windows Vertically (does its best to place all open windows re-sized on your desktop)
- Tile Windows Horizontally (does its best to place all open windows re-sized on your desktop)

This is by far the easiest. I use it in a multiple monitor set on my laptop when power goes out and I loose the second monitor. I can pull all the windows onto my main monitor (laptop). Very easy, quick.

Comment: This method also affects all the other visible windows.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications don't respond to activating the window plus using alt+space+m, such as FSCapture (faststone screen capture). **WindowSpace** (free trial) worked to move it back onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

A technique that often works is this:

- Right-click in the taskbar and choose "Show Desktop"
- Right-click on the problem program task and choose "Restore"
- Right-click on the some other program's task and choose "Restore"
- Right-click in the taskbar and choose "Cascade Windows"

This normally causes the window parameters to fit onto the current screen. Having only two active windows keeps most window positions unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There is (or was) an extremely good program called Shove-It for Windows. Used to be at www.phord.com but it's been taken down now. Basically just run it and it will automatically detect any windows that have opened with their contents even partially off-screen, and either "shove" them back into the viewing portal area or else resize them if necessary, all automatically. I managed to locate an old beta of it which is free, will share via Sugarsync. https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D290041_6932435_98576

Comment: Just an FYI, most users here would be pretty skeptical of downloading a random zip file from the internet, even with background.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install **aero snap** plugin.
2. Move the screen with the hotkey: **Win + arrows**

Answer (score 0):

One more option which allows to not affect other window positions and to avoid mouse-dragging: run an additional instance of the **same** application (in case currently there is only one), so that the following menu is available when you press Shift + right mouse click:
[image]