# How can I move an unmovable window in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, desktop

I'm using Windows XP on a company issued computer at a client I work for and they have a password changing utility that pops up and forces you to change your password every month or so. They've disabled closing, minimizing, or moving the password changer application around. It also sits in front of any other application on your desktop, so you can't see anything behind it. The move option is even disabled when you click on the app in the task bar.

Here is the context menu when I click on the app in the system tray:

[image]

Here is what I see in the menu when I click on the top left icon on the app:

[image]

After you change your password, it forces you to restart your machine, but it gives you a chance to close your apps. The problem is that the password changer is often times sitting right on top of any dialog boxes that pop up when you try to close your apps.

I don't want to kill the app, because I've been warned that they monitor for that and will get in trouble. But, I would like to be able to move it so that I can close my apps before restarting my machine. Is there any way (utility) to force a window to move even if moving is disabled?

Comment: It might be worth making the IT dept. aware of the issue, if the app is developed in house they may be able to change the default positon to top left or somewhere else out of the way.

Comment: They're very aware and very unwilling to change the design. :-/

Comment: Sounds friendly, that's a spectacularly stupid piece of design unless they're trying to annoy their users into changing their passwords.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not getting you wrong then you should try to press `Alt+Tab` key and select the windows you want to move and then again press the `Alt+Spacebar` and press `M`. Now you can move your windows anywhere on desktop using arrow keys and press Enter to drop it where you want.

**Edit**

I tried with Google and found a solution on our great community and the answer given by the KCotreau is approximate same but there is another solution provided by the user by a python script to move windows try with that. This is the [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/316282/what-can-i-do-to-retrieve-windows-that-have-gone-off-screen/316285#316285). Hope it will help you. Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry, but you are getting me wrong. :)  They have programmatically disabled the ability to move things around. The standard move functionality is disabled for that application. You can't get to it through application menus, shortcuts, or context-menus.

Comment: You're getting @avirk wrong. He's suggesting moving *the other* windows around using the keystrokes he gave, which will almost certainly work. Actually try it.

Comment: Ahh, yes, but the problem is that some dialog boxes are always placed in the center of the screen (right under the unmovable window), and repositioning some apps does not reposition where the dialog pops up. You also don't have control to move when there is a dialog box that is already open, so if you have one open when the password changer pops up, you can't even get to it to see the options. Yes, @avirk has an sometimes useful workaround, but it doesn't answer the question of how I can move the restricted window.