# Recover OffScreen Window in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1

Someone asked a very similar question in regards to window recovery for windows xp: [Similar Recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/316282/what-can-i-do-to-retrieve-windows-that-have-gone-off-screen)

I'm using windows 8 (or 8.1 now). I run Dual Monitors. On Monitor 2 I sometimes have the input switched to something else other than the windows display (Mac or PS3). If there was a program that was displaying on Window #2 that does not have 'move' where I could potentially alt-space-m arrow keys. Is there another way to get that program to display on Window #1?

I tried right click on the program and doesn't seem to be anything there.
I tried Windows Key and Arrows.
I Tried right click toolbar and cascade.

I'm hoping this is a DUP or Softball question because this annoys the crap out of me.

Thanks!!

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1206086/win8-1-program-thinks-it-is-on-a-phantom-monitor-moves-out-of-view-when-invok and https://superuser.com/questions/663443/recover-offscreen-window-in-windows-8?rq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Can't be sure for Win8, but for Win7, a trick to force all apps to screen 1 (main screen): press `Windows+P` until and select `Computer only`. This forces all apps to rearrange it's window to main monitor only.

[image: Computer only]

Alternatively, if you know the off screen program is active, press and hold <kbd>Windows</kbd> and then press <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> Arrow key multiple times until it moves into your viewable screen.

Comment: The Windows+left shortcut was brilliant, and worked really well.... for about a month.  Now it has inexplicably ceased to function.  Fortunately, the Windows+P trick still works, for now.

Comment: Win+P didn't work for me, but Win+Left did :)

Answer (score 32):

For Windows 8...

Here is what I did! Seems the secret is that the arrow keys move one space and not an entire screen...

- select the program/window in the task bar
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>
- <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>
- hold the left arrow key down until it moves across

Comment: This way works for me in Windows 8.1

Comment: And Windows 10 too

Comment: Unbelievable that this still happens on Windows in 2016. Another reason I find I'm ~20% more productive on OSX.

Comment: Fails if the other window is maximized, for some reason, at least on Win 8.1.  Windows+left arrow is much easier, anyway, or Windows+P.

Comment: @JarrodSmith When I first Googled for a solution, most of the results were by OSX users who have the same problem!

Answer (score 15):

One option is to go with the old-shcool <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to move the window:

- Activate the app that you want to move (say, with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>M</kbd> (for Move)

  - You should now see the cursor on the edge of the screen where the window is lost (or centered on the window's title bar if it is visible)
- Use the arrow keys to move the window into sight
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to release the window

Comment: Thanks @GaTechThomas! It amazes me that BASIC/OBVIOUS stuff is STILL a issue within the (sadly) most popular OS on planet. Do they actually test any UX scenarios? Each time my montior config changes the window positions goes to hell. Yeah. I like to change my monitor config and positions, what I want is a OS capable of compensate within reason and logic for that. 

The cursor keys worked for me within 8.1, the mouse move didn't. Odd. Stupid. Windows.

Comment: I expect that the video drivers and display management software are part of the problem. When docked, my laptop has both an nVidia card and an Intel card, and each has its own drivers and display management software. Should the OS disallow custom display management in favor of its own? That wouldn't be well received. Given the complexity of writing an operating system in which the hardware used is wide open, I think that Microsoft has done an amazing job.

Comment: I think my instructions are a bit off. Refactoring.

Comment: still works in win10!

Answer (score 4):

You can try the Windows Snap feature to cycle the window you want back to the screen you can see. You can use `Win Key + Left/Right` to move a window where you like.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows7/products/features/snap

Comment: I tried the Windows Key and it just didn't work for me. Who knows I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: It could be that the window can't be resized. I see you've found your answer though!

Comment: Indeed! works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

Use a docked magnifier!

1. Open the magnifier app and switch to docked view. Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
2. Make sure you can move your mouse to the secondary desktop. If you can't, extend your desktop after pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Now you can see what is around your mouse, so just grab your window and drag it back.

[image: Retrieving window with magnifier.]