# Win8 animation shows a window opening offscreen. How do I find it?

Tags: windows-8

I have one program that seems to remember when my HDMI external was set up to be on the opposite side as it is now.

So when I click on the task bar icon I can see the animation of it flying off in the wrong direction and out of view.

I remember the "Move" function exists but can't figure out how to do it when the whole thing is invisible.  Seems to me all I should have to do is hold the Windows button and use arrows until it shows.  But I can't make that work even though the animation shows which direction it went.

So my question is, (without going into display properties and switching things all around), how can I move that program so it is visible?

Comment: No, because that question is specific to Windows XP and this is for Windows 8.1

Comment: Maybe should be linked to this one for Windows 8:  https://superuser.com/questions/663443/recover-offscreen-window-in-windows-8

Comment: That question is about traditional Windows usage, the OP just happened to be using XP at the time.  The answers apply to multiple/all versions, including 7, 8 and 10, hence why it's what we point to. The answer you accepted here is in those answers as well: https://superuser.com/a/1005011/23133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this happen to PowerShell of all things.  I hold Shift while right-clicking on the icon on the Taskbar, select Move, then use the right/left arrows to bring the menu back onto the screen, then click on the program's window with the mouse.

Comment: This is very easy to remember.  It is very similar to earlier Windows so is basically built into my muscle memory.  So thank you for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Two options for bringing an out of screen window back:

- `Win`+`Left` / `Win`+`Right` / `Win`+`Up` (move/resize the active window to predefined screen positions)
- Press and release `Alt`, then press and release `Space`. This should bring up the context menu of the active window where you can select "move". This will make the window movable with your arrow keys and/or mouse. If you want to move it with your mouse you'll first have to make it movable with the arrow keys.

Im not sure if they work in your case though, but I think they should because they're windows features and the wrong position seems to be caused by your program.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are solid solutions. Another command would be Win + Shift + Left/Right. This will allow you to move the selected application window from monitor to monitor.

Comment: Now that one I can remember.  It is even easier.  Thanks.  Upvote.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/55798/23133